# Unable to update collaboration, using update collaboration API in box-java-sdk-v2

Tags: box-api

I am trying to integrate Box with [Kerika](http://kerika.com) using [box-java-sdk-v2](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2b). Library is added as maven dependency (net.box:boxjavalibv2) in the project.

Everything is working fine, except the update collaboration API. API call from the project looks like follow:

```
BoxCollabRequestObject requestObject = BoxCollabRequestObject.updateCollaborationObject(permission);
return client().getCollaborationsManager().
updateCollaboration(collaborationId, requestObject);
```

I searched google a lot to find the solution of this. But, I didn't get any. So, I have logged the issue at [box-java-sdk-v2 issues](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk-v2/issues/151) on GitLab.

After spending some more time after a day a found that issue is with the Java library itself. There isn't any problem with Box API. I concluded this by accessing [REST API directly](https://developers.box.com/docs/#collaborations-edit-a-collaboration) from [Advanced REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) instead of Java library, and it worked.

So, as work around (Until the bug from the Java SDK is not officially fixed and release), I have updated my code as follows:

```
// As client library update function is not working properly so I have written custom code to deal with it.
BoxCollabRequestObject requestObject = BoxCollabRequestObject.updateCollabObjects(permission);
BoxCollaborationsManagerImpl boxCollaborationsManager = (BoxCollaborationsManagerImpl)client().getCollaborationsManager();
BoxUpdateCollaborationRequest request = new BoxUpdateCollaborationRequest(boxCollaborationsManager.getConfig(), boxCollaborationsManager.getJSONParser(), collaborationId, requestObject);
return (BoxCollaboration) boxCollaborationsManager.getResponseAndParseAndTryCast(request, BoxResourceType.COLLABORATION, boxCollaborationsManager.getJSONParser());
```

and the `BoxUpdateCollaborationRequest` class in the above code is self made. It looks like as follow:

```
public class BoxUpdateCollaborationRequest extends DefaultBoxRequest
{
    private static final String URI = "/collaborations/%s";

    public BoxUpdateCollaborationRequest(IBoxConfig config, IBoxJSONParser parser, String id, BoxCollabRequestObject requestObject) throws BoxRestException
    {
        super(config, parser, getUri(id), RestMethod.PUT, requestObject);
    }

    public static String getUri(final String id) {
        return String.format(URI, id);
    }
}
```

I noticed that the real problem in their original implementation is just the constant. It should be

```
private static final String URI = "/collaborations/%s";
```

Instead of

```
private static final String URI = "/collaboration/%s";
```

I am filing this issue here to help others who is having the same issue and searching Stack Overflow for the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the spelunking and finding the cause of the bug @chirag.  If you want you can also submit your change as a pull request on the github project.  Then you get full glory points for your contribution.

Comment: Sure, I would like to contribute to the project. I will do this from next time. Right now my bug has been fixed and included in the new version

Comment: Merged and fixed into the project